# In componentWillReceiveProps, this.props and nextProps are always the same

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, lifecycle

this.props and nextProps in the componentReceive are always the same. Even though the state changes, componentWillReceiveProps has not been called.

I haven't mutated any redux store object or state object in the parent component.

Parent component:

```
<Drawer
visible={visible}
>
  <ChildComponent data={data} />
/>
```

Child Component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
// this lifecycle is not even being called when I update the props
 if(this.props.data !== nextProps.data){
  this.setState({value: nextProps.data.inputValue});
 }
}
onChange = e => {
 this.setState({value: e})
}
render(){
 return(
  <input value={this.state.value} onChange={e => this.onChange(e.target.value)}/>
 )
}
```

FYI: visible and data are passed as props fro redux store.

this.props.data is always equal to nextProps.data when I use componentWillReceiveProps in the child component. It should differ.

Comment: check the Reducer file where you are updating the value and make sure you have proper connection with the action and reducer while dispatching..

Comment: Update your code also so that other peoples will help you..

Comment: I've checked that, it has been properly bound with the actions @SivaprakashD

Comment: @GowthamKoushik can you expose some code of the component where you are using `<ChildComponent data={data} />`.

Comment: @PrabhatMishra Is it okay now, this is the actual use case.

Comment: nope, the code of the component from where you are passing `data` props.

Comment: There is actually a container(HOC) which uses connect to get state from store using mapsToProps. Thats it nothing other than that

Comment: @GowthamKoushik update the full code of each component.

Comment: @GowthamKoushik have you updating the state value by using action dispatch?

Comment: Yes I've used action to update the variable in the store.

Comment: So you are facing this issue when 'onChange' function is triggerd right ( while update the input value) ?

Comment: To be exact I've some values in the table. In each row there will be edit button. When the edit button is clicked, a modal will be appeared with the pre populated data. So I was not able to bind those values into the modal. The value is always the initial value and not changing. This is the issue I'm facing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197816/discussion-between-sivaprakash-d-and-gowtham-koushik).